# Ext.draw.Sprite scale glitch

Tags: javascript, extjs, svg, raphael

I am doing zooming tool and have some problem with Sprite.setAttributes({scale: {…});
Centered by center of canvas...

http://teempla.com/sites/all/themes/teamplan/d2d/ - here is it.

Try to draw two or more lines with pencil and press Zoom + you will see that there are floating. It's Wrong. And strange, 'corse they position relative center.

pice of click-event code:

```
click: function( e, t, eOpts ){
   d2dModel.set('zoom',d2dModel.get('zoom')+0.1);
  var draw = Ext.ComponentManager.get(Ext.select('.d2d-draw-panel',true).elements[0].id);
  for (var i in draw.surface.items.map){
     draw.surface.items.map[i].setAttributes({
        scale: {
           cx: d2dModel.get('width')/2,
           cy: d2dModel.get('height')/2,
           x: d2dModel.get('zoom'),
           y: d2dModel.get('zoom')
        }
     }, true);
 }
}
```

In Raphael.JS i made it with

```
el.transform('s'+zoom+','+zoom+','+w/2+','+h/2);
```

And it works fine.

Thank's for any ideas!

Comment: You aren't really zooming when I press the zoom button, you're just making the sprites bigger (as you're saying). You should scale the canvas instead. I've done this in the past. Let me look the code up for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try zooming on your surface by using setViewBox

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/source/Surface.html#Ext-draw-Surface-method-setViewBox

What I did in my project was this:

```
    var bbox = draw.surface.items.getBBox();
    draw.surface.setViewBox(bbox.x, bbox.y, draw.getSize().width / zoomValue, draw.getSize().height / zoomValue);
```

Note that this was during ext 4 beta, but it should be almost the same now.

Comment: You wore right!
Thank's a lot! I added your code - and it works as better, BUT why all paths floating at left!? I tried change x and y values of in `setViewBox` function - but it does not help... were can be error?
new version [here](http://teempla.com/sites/all/themes/teamplan/d2d/)

Comment: It's probably something with the x and the y values. Try playing around with those.